# Creating .exe in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have developed a window based application in C#. I have used Crystal reports to show data and a.mdf database Now i want to create **an exe file which contains crystal reports,database in its perquisites**,and when i install it on any computer it installs the crystal reports and database from same location as exe.

Comment: to do this you should create a new project which is a setup and deployment type

Answer (score 1):

Create a setup using [Inno Setup](http://jrsoftware.org/isdl.php) and make it install your prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio Setup Project. In Setup Project, follow `New Project > Other Project Types > Setup and Deployment > Visual Studio Installer`. Check out [.NET Framework Deployment Guide for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx)

Comment: .vdproj is no longer supported by Microsoft and is absent in VS2012, so even in vs2010 it's not a particularly future proof option. It seems that you are recommending .vsix, which is entirely inappropriate.

Comment: @spender - What do you have against .vsix files?  Are those not simply just Visual Studio Extension files?  Install Shield and Wix Toolset appear to be the best options currently.  http://wix.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Ramhound If I'm not mistaken, "Visual Studio Installer" is for making vsix, right? Wouldn't be much use for distibuting an exe file. FWIW, Wix is what we *mostly* use... don't much like InsShield's pikey interface but probably most approriate here.

Comment: @spender - As you point out Microsoft dropped support for the "visual Studio Setup Projects" with VS2012 for many reasons.  Most versions of Visual Studio has come with Install Shield for awhile now.  The "Setup Project" could build and compile `.msi` files.  It actually appears that `.vsix` files are just Visual Studio Extensions not actual programs.  The chart that Soner linked to gives all the current options ( outside of programs like Inno Setup of course ) that Microsoft suggests using.